# Primary key from parent class using Room?

Tags: android, primary-key, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am using Android Architecture Components. Hence using `Room` 'ORM'. I have a class `EQPreset` that has a member `String presetName`. This class has a child class called `UserDefinedEQPreset` and it contains an `int[] arr`. I have declared the child class `EQPreset` and entity using `@Entity` annotation, since only this subtype I want to store in db. Now I want to use parent class's (`EQPreset`) member `String presetName` to be used as `primary key`. How to declare a member of parent class as `primary key` while using `Room`. I know `@Primarykey` annotation is used to declare the primary key. But how to use parent class's member as `primary key`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the `@PrimaryKey` annotation on the parent class' field. Done.

For example, in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/v0.1/Trips/RoomRelations), I have an `abstract class Plan` with `@PrimaryKey
public final String id`. All subclasses, such as `Trip`, inherit that `@PrimaryKey` definition.

Not everything inherits properly (e.g., `@TypeConverters` works on fields but not on classes), but `@PrimaryKey` seems to.

Comment: Commonsware can i do the other way round ? Lets say if i have a table Feed(@Entity) & using @Embedded (on Post)  i add more fields into Feed table from my class Post but i want to specify primary key from class Post

Comment: @Gautam: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, as I do not completely understand what you are trying to do. Sorry!

Comment: @CommonsWare This should not be the accepted answer. Consider the example where the parent class is in a different project imported from Maven / Gradle as is common if, for example, I want to create a basic database table structure and use subclasses to define specifics for ORM implementation (ie, Room children for Android, Hibernate children for Spring impl). Your solution implies that the original library requires the Android Room dependency, which undermines any generic structure and bloats the library package unnecessarily since the child project should contain the impl specifics of Room.

Comment: @moonlightcheese: If I understand you correctly, what you are seeking is not supported by Room.

Comment: @CommonsWare This answer is at least somewhat close.  The `primaryKeys` attribute allows defining any variable (even from parent classes) as a primary key.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52760093/329993

Answer (score 1):

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["presetName"])
class UserDefinedEQPreset extends EQPreset{
    ...
}
```

I think this is what you're looking for. Use the `primaryKeys` attribute on the `Entity` annotation to specify the primary key. You can also use this to specify composite primary keys.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I didn't know this attribute existed for Entity annotations. Very handy! Thanks for this. However, there appear to be some limitations. For example, aggregate keys will not be possible and autogenerated values also are not available if the `@PrimaryKey` is defined with this attribute. It would be nice if they extended more capability to this attribute! https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Entity#primaryKeys()